# How does electric field lines pass through dielectric?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electric-current

[image]

From being a conductor we have J⃗ =σE⃗
where σ
is the conductivity, J⃗
is the current density, and E⃗
is the E field.

From electrostatic equilibrium we have J⃗ =0
.

From this statement we can conclude that in an electrostatic condition.... If The current flowing through an area is zero then the current density will also be zero then if current density is zero then the electric field intensity in a dielectric will also be zero.... This mean that in a dielectric the electric field lines must also be zero then how Does the image says that""electric fields can pass through dielectrics" "??

Answer (score 2):

> if current density is zero then the electric field intensity in a dielectric will also be zero

This is the part that doesn’t hold. In a conductor we have Ohm’s law: $\vec J =\sigma \vec E$. But dielectrics are not conductors and Ohm’s law does not hold. Instead, $$\vec P=\epsilon_0 \chi_r \vec E$$

So $\vec J=0$ implies $\vec E=0$ for a conductor, but not a dielectric. In a dielectric the relationship is between the E field and the polarization, not between the E field and the current density. You can have a static E field in a dielectric simply by having a static polarization, $\vec P$.